# Standard ML: Binary Tree Datatype

Tags: functional-programming, sml

My notes include the following definition for a binary tree:

```
datatype tree = Empty | Node of tree * int * tree
```

How do I know whether the second option in the definition is supposed to mean:

```
Node of (tree * int * tree)
```

or

```
Node of tree * int * tree?
```

Thanks,

bclayman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node of (tree * int * tree)` and `Node of tree * int * tree` are the same

Comment: I was thinking it might be `(Node of tree) * int * tree`...thanks again!

Comment: @bclayman: Each branch in a datatype declaration is either `Constructor` or `Constructor of type`. So `(Node of tree) * int * tree` wouldn't be well-formed. By the way -- if Matt's answer solved your problem, the best way to thank him is to "accept" the answer by clicking the green checkbox to the left of it. This will let others know that your problem has been solved, and will give him +15 reputation points (and yourself +2).